# How to get the name from lines by removing everything from '[' to end(using split on'[ed' and selecting the first element )

Tags: python, string, split

```
file = open('university_towns.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()
lst = []; state = ''; region = ''
for name in lines:
    if name == '[ed':
        state = name.split('[ed',0)
```

If I run the above code, then, the following output is obtained

```
['Alabama[edit]\n',
'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\n',
'Florence (University of North Alabama)\n',
'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\n',
'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\n',
'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\n',
'Troy (Troy University)[2]\n',
'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]\n',
'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]\n',
'Alaska[edit]\n',
'Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]\n',
'Arizona[edit]\n',
'Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]\n',
'Tempe (Arizona State University)\n',
'Tucson (University of Arizona)\n',
```

But I only want the elements which end with [ed

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: The shown code doesn't output anything.

Comment: The code reads a file into lines variable. I don't have the physical file - it's an online assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = []
for name in lines:
    if '[edit]' in name:
        items.append(name.split('[')[0])
print(items)
```

can you please try this

Comment: I got the following output: `Alabama[edit]

Alaska[edit]

Arizona[edit]`

Comment: @SaifMehdi so now you need to remove edit at the end of each element right?

Comment: Thanks. I have to similarly get the other elements which have [1],[2],[3], etc.  at the end

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a regular expression. `Split` will return the original string as a 1-element list when no split takes place. Note in the example below, I assume you want lines that end in `'[edit]'`.

Also you should use a context manager and avoid calling readlines when iterating over a text file.

```
import re

patt = r'\[edit\]$'

with open('university_towns.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(patt, line):
            # do something here
```